# Could not load cxf

Tags: java, maven, websphere, cxf

I'm trying to deploy and start application with cxf and spring libraries in WebSphere 9.

The application has started with next errors in logs:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionBuilderRegistryImpl.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:183)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.getClassObject(Extension.java:199)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:161)
    at **com.ttc.cg.audit.config.CxfAuditBusConfig.bus(CxfAuditBusConfig.java:29)
    at comp.ttc.cg.audit.config.CxfAuditBusConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36db2ba1.CGLIB$bus$0(<generated>)
    at com.ttc.cg.audit.config.CxfAuditBusConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36db2ba1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7738c735.invoke(<generated>)
    at** org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.ttc.cg.audit.config.CxfAuditBusConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$36db2ba1.bus(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 86 common frames omitted
```

I set "local class loading first" in server1 and application (class loader) parameters.

In POM file there are next dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the class with errors contains next inmport:

```
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Interceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
```

Help me pls.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html ?  

It suggests that you disable the JAX-WS engine built in to WAS and set the classloader delegation policy to parent last (so that you load your own CXF implementation rather than WAS's).  HTH, Andy

Comment: @Andy McCright Yes, I did this tutorial, but the same problem.